# Angular: ERROR in Unexpected value 'CdkScrollableModule

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I did npm update and suddenly I find myself in a situation where my app stopped working

I encountered the following issue:

```
ERROR in Unexpected value 'CdkScrollableModule in /Users/***/dev/FEprojects/GsmMusicApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/index.d.ts' imported by the module 'MatSidenavModule in /Users/***/dev/FEprojects/GsmMusicApp/node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/index.d.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
Can't export value CdkScrollableModule in /Users/***/dev/FEprojects/GsmMusicApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/index.d.ts from MatSidenavModule in /Users/***/dev/FEprojects/GsmMusicApp/node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/index.d.ts as it was neither declared nor imported!
Can't export value CdkScrollableModule in /Users/***/dev/FEprojects/GsmMusicApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/index.d.ts from MatMenuModule in /Users/***/dev/FEprojects/GsmMusicApp/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/index.d.ts as it was neither declared nor imported!
Can't export value CdkScrollableModule in /Users/***/dev/FEprojects/GsmMusicApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/index.d.ts from MatSelectModule in /Users/***/dev/FEprojects/GsmMusicApp/node_modules/@angular/material/select/index.d.ts as it was neither declared nor imported!
Can't export value CdkScrollableModule in /Users/***/dev/FEprojects/GsmMusicApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/index.d.ts from MatTooltipModule in /Users/***/dev/FEprojects/GsmMusicApp/node_modules/@angular/material/tooltip/index.d.ts as it was neither declared nor imported!
```

I have tried to add CdkScrollableModule in AppModule, but that didn't do anything.

How do I solve this?

Regards,

Rick

ng version:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.12
Node: 13.11.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.0.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: No

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.12
@angular/cdk                      9.1.3
@angular/cli                      9.1.12
@angular/material                 9.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.8
@schematics/angular               9.1.12
@schematics/update                0.901.12
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.43.0
```

npm version:

```
{
  'gsm-music-app': '0.0.0',
  npm: '6.14.5',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '36.0',
  icu: '65.1',
  llhttp: '2.0.4',
  modules: '79',
  napi: '6',
  nghttp2: '1.40.0',
  node: '13.11.0',
  openssl: '1.1.1d',
  tz: '2019c',
  unicode: '12.1',
  uv: '1.34.2',
  v8: '7.9.317.25-node.29',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}
```

Comment: Please try to delete the node_modules directory completely and run "npm install" again.

Comment: which one? node_modules exists as multiple directories, if I remove the most top level one, npm install does not work anymore

Comment: I meant the node_modules directory which is on your project level, so next to the location of the package.json or angular.json (top-level). Why isn't npm install working anymore? Did you execute the command in the correct directory?

Comment: Ok, now I found the right folder, and removed it, and npm install worked, but ng serve still reports same problem. npm install reported this:
https://pastebin.com/XbSaeAdz (had to use pastebin due to character limitation in coments)

Comment: ok, figured it out, had to install those versions "npm install" warned about, its working now. However I don't know what to do with the warning about @ngtools/webpack@10.0.8, it requires typescript 3.9> but angular 9 requires typescript <3.8 . What do I do with that?

Comment: There might be some mismatch with your package versions. I'd recommend that you take a look at https://update.angular.io/ so that you can update Angular to a proper version. Hopefully that helps you further.

Comment: thanks, yes I accidentally started the migration to Angular 9 and broke so much stuff. I'm a java programmer and angular is a now area for me. I must say I don't find it all very straightforward. Stuff breaks easily. Anyways, thank you very much for your quick support!